# Range = column found before [vba]

Tags: excel, vba

I work currently to create a VBA macro which will search for the column called "Email" or "Email - personal email" (this is the same column but these 2 names are substitutes).

So first search for the Email column, while found then check if there are any dots at the end of the email addresses. If yes it should delete them.

I have limited VBA knowledge and I am not the IT preson. So I mostly use and amend existing scripts which I found on the internet. Below is the code which I made combining 2 macros. It works fine but only when the email column is in the same place (in this case column S). How should I amend the code to use the column where Email header had been spotted?

**My code:**

```
Sub GOOD_WORKS_No_Dots_at_End_of_Emails()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    strSearch = "Email*"

    Set aCell = Sheet2.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Data").Activate
            Dim LR As Long, i As Long
            LR = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To LR
                With Range("S" & i)
                    If Right(.Value, 1) = "." Then .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1)
                End With
            Next i
            Sheets("Automation").Activate
            MsgBox "No Dots at the end of email addresses - Done!"
            End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following should work

```
'rowNum<~~~ Enter the row number your "Header fields" are in
 'returns a dictionary object
Function getAllColNum(ByVal rowNum As Long, ByVal searchString As Variant) As Object
    Dim allColNum As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim width As Long
    Set allColNum = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    colNum = 1
    With ActiveSheet
        width = .Cells(rowNum, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To width
             If InStr(UCase(Trim(.Cells(rowNum, i).Value)), UCase(Trim(searchString))) > 0 Then
                 allColNum.Add i, ""
             End If '
        Next i
    End With
    Set getAllColNum = allColNum
End Function



Sub GOOD_WORKS_No_Dots_at_End_of_Emails()
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "Email"
    Dim colNum As Variant
    Dim allColNum As Object
    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Set allColNum = getAllColNum(1, searchString)
    For Each colNum In allColNum
        LR = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LR
            With Range(Cells(i, colNum), Cells(i, colNum))
                If Right(.Value, 1) = "." Then .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1)
            End With
        Next i
    Next colNum
    Sheets("Automation").Activate
    MsgBox "No Dots at the end of email addresses - Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still looks for the S range. How should I amend the rowNum? Where exactly the changes should be done. My case is quite simple - all the headers are in the 1st row

Comment: did you copied ALL of my code?  It searches from column A to whatever columns you have for "Email" or "Email - personal email" 

If "Email" appears in column A, it should work, where is your "Email" column?

Comment: I capied all the code, I didn't change anything and when I run the macro it finishes with the message that it's done but dots has not been deleted from the end of email addresses. Email is usually stored in the column R but there are some files which have Emails in the column S. Also I was thinking about using 1 search string as Email* <-- where it catches everything which has email in its title. Is it possible?

Comment: My problem, I mislook one of the coding part that I needed to change, wait.

Comment: I fixed the code, now it should search for column "R" because it comes before column S. For your 2nd request, I can do it after ~ 4 hours when I have time.

Comment: Great Larry! it works now. Ok no worries. I will wait until you have some time

Comment: @mgunia Hi, i changed the code, please let me know if it's working properly, it should be able to iterate through ALL columns header containing email. Please mark this answer as accept if it works perfectly for you. And please describe your problem in detail, in parts next time. **EDIT** I edited the code, please copy it again